# какую нейронную сеть можно применить для прохождения тетриса?

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети

есть тетрис на js, есть нейронная сеть на js которая умеет обучаться чтоб делать операции or xor and.

можно ли их объединить, или нужно что то другое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретически да:

Мы определяем матрицу с активной фигурой, а далее окно (т.е. размеры этой матрицы) двигаем по верху уже установленных фигур.

Таким образом `summ += a[i][j] !== b[i][j]`, то место где `summ` больше - является тем местом куда ставить фигуру. Что-то вроде распознавания инвертированного образа.

Обучение это подача на вход фигуры, а на выход - инвертированное значение. Таким образом сеть будет обучаться искать инвертированный образ. Ошибку можно считать по формуле которой я дал, она будет искать расстояние (количество различий) между фигурами.

Это общее, достаточно поверхностное описание подхода который может основываться на булевых операциях, что может быть использовано в вашем случае.

А вообще я не специалист в нейросетях)